# css border radius for mozilla

Tags: css

On the given page below the border radius for the #topnav doesnt work for mozilla but works for google chrome, i use the following css code:

http://www.kbay.in

```css
#topnav { display:inline-block;float: right; text-align: right; background: #e4f4fe; 
    border:1px solid #e4f4fe;
    border-bottom-color: #e4f4fe;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: solid; 
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px; 
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px; 
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    margin-right: 90px; margin-top: 0px;
    width:265px;}5E9DC8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new Firefox has now the unprefixed version of `border-radius`.

Though the old version was

```css
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
```

you now have to take

```css
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
```

for the new Firefox. That's why you always have to declare the official version **last** (so no overriding can happen).

```css
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px; 
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
/*last border-radius declaration has to be the standard one*/
border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
```

Nonetheless, it still should work. Perhaps you have some other rule overriding this one? ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zbpER/)) Also, delete the `5E9DC8` behind your ruleblock.

Btw, you are on the safe side if you just choose the shorthand notation because it has no notation-differences.

Comment: You have a string behind that rule - delete it.

Comment: You mean this string: -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;  ??

Comment: No, behinde the block: 5E9DC8

Comment: ohh...i reset the browsers cache and it worked like charm ..thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, now, with last browser version, old prefixes ( -o, -moz, -webkit ) are deleted, 
just use "border-radius" for all new browser ( ie, opera, chrome and firefox) it's a [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corners)
but, for "old" browser, continue to use old profixes,

existing one specific website for generate css border radius code [just here](http://border-radius.com/).